# mutt & mutt_oauth.py - mutt_account_getoauthbearer: Command Returned Empty String

Tags: mutt

I am trying to setup the Mutt terminal email client with an Exchange 365 email account. I am using `mutt_oauth.py` in order to facilitate the OAuth flow.

I have followed the instructions in the [README](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/contrib/mutt_oauth2.py.README) but am running into an issue. When I load mutt, it tries to login but returns the following error:

```
mutt_account_getoauthbearer: Command returned empty string
```

Here is the output of `mutt -d 5`:

```
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Mutt/2.2.7 (2022-08-07) debugging at level 5
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] In mutt_reflow_windows
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] In mutt_reflow_windows
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] In mutt_reflow_windows
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] In mutt_reflow_windows
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Reading configuration file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mutt/2.2.7/etc/Muttrc'.
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047c9e90, *ldata = 0x0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added */.* [9]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047c9ea0, *ldata = 0x0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added text/x-vcard [7]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added application/pgp.* [2]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047c9ea0, *ldata = 0x600001d588d0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: skipping text/x-vcard
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: skipping application/pgp.*
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added application/x-pkcs7-.* [2]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047ca300, *ldata = 0x0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added text/plain [7]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047c9ea0, *ldata = 0x600001d588d0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: skipping text/x-vcard
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: skipping application/pgp.*
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: skipping application/x-pkcs7-.*
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added message/external-body [4]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: ldata = 0x1047ca308, *ldata = 0x0
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] parse_attach_list: added message/external-body [4]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Reading configuration file '/Users/jlcarveth/.mutt/muttrc'.
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Using default IMAP port 143
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Using default IMAPS port 993
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Setting $hostname
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] getdnsdomainname(): localdomain
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] $hostname set to "JLCM2.localdomain"
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Reading imap://outlook.office365.com/INBOX...
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Looking up outlook.office365.com...
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Connecting to outlook.office365.com...
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Connected to outlook.office365.com:143 on fd=7
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] imap_cmd_step: grew buffer to 512 bytes
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7< * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [***OMITTED***]
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] IMAP queue drained
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7> a0000 CAPABILITY
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7< * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] Handling CAPABILITY
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7< a0000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] IMAP queue drained
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7> a0001 STARTTLS
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] 7< a0001 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] IMAP queue drained
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] ssl_load_certificates: loading trusted certificates
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] mutt_ssl_starttls: Error loading trusted certificates
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] ssl_verify_callback: checking cert chain entry /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA (preverify: 1 skipmode: 0)
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] ssl_verify_callback: checking cert chain entry /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1 (preverify: 1 skipmode: 0)
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] ssl_verify_callback: checking cert chain entry /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=outlook.com (preverify: 1 skipmode: 0)
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] ssl_verify_callback: hostname check passed
[2022-10-19 13:49:59] TLSv1.2 connection using TLSv1.2 (ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] 7> a0002 CAPABILITY
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] 7< * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] Handling CAPABILITY
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] 7< a0002 OK CAPABILITY completed.
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] IMAP queue drained
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] imap_authenticate: Trying method oauthbearer
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] SASL local ip: 192.168.1.248;55042, remote ip:52.96.88.162;143
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] External SSF: 256
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] mutt_sasl_cb_authname: getting user for outlook.office365.com:143
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] imap_auth_sasl: oauthbearer unavailable
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] imap_authenticate: Trying method xoauth2
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] Authenticating (XOAUTH2)...
[2022-10-19 13:50:00] mutt_account_getoauthbearer: Command returned empty string
[2022-10-19 13:50:02] mutt_index_menu[827]: Got op 99
[2022-10-19 13:50:02] q: unknown command
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] mutt_index_menu[827]: Got op 177
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] Closing connection to outlook.office365.com...
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] 7> a0003 LOGOUT
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] 7< * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server IMAP4 server signing off.
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] Handling BYE
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] 7< a0003 OK LOGOUT completed.
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] IMAP queue drained
[2022-10-19 13:50:03] mutt_buffer_pool_free: 10 of 10 returned to pool
```

I am unsure how to resolve this error. My tokens seem to be valid when I run `python3 mutt_oauth.py my@email.com.tokens --verbose --test`, as the tokens are printed and no issues.

My `~/.mutt/muttrc` is quite simple:

```
set imap_user="***OMITTED***"
set folder="imap://outlook.office365.com/"
#set imap_pass='***OMITTED***'
set smtp_url = "smtp://${imap_user}@smtp.office365.com:587/"
set imap_authenticators="oauthbearer:xoauth2"
set imap_oauth_refresh_command="/Users/jlcarveth/mutt_oauth.py \
    --quiet ${imap_user}.tokens"
set smtp_authenticators='${imap_authenticators}'
set smtp_oauth_refresh_command=${imap_oauth_refresh_command}
set spoolfile=+INBOX

# Store message headers locally to speed things up
set header_cache=~/.cache/mutt
set message_cachedir=~/.cache/mutt

# Allow mutt to open an IMAP connection passively
unset imap_passive

set imap_keepalive = 300
```

mutt v 2.2.7

Answer (score 0):

This line here

```
set imap_oauth_refresh_command="/Users/jlcarveth/mutt_oauth.py \
--quiet ${imap_user}.tokens"
```

`${imap_user}.tokens` is not an absoule path. My guess is that is your issue. Try adding the full path to your tokens file there.

Answer (score 0):

Mutt's `mutt_account_getoauthbearer` method tries to use whatever is defined by your `imap_oauth_refresh_command` to get / refresh the token. `Command returned empty string` means for some reason the call to the external script has failed. Some possible reasons:

- The path to the external refresh command is incorrect. (You specified `mutt_oauth.py`. Did you mean `mutt_oauth2.py`, or have you renamed the script?)
- The path to `${imap_user}.tokens` is incorrect. (As @mokchira points out it needs to be the full path to your token storage.)
- Your key is secured by a passphrase but `gpg-agent` is not able to prompt for the passphrase because the `GPG_TTY` environment variable is not set correctly for your shell.

If running `/path/to/mutt_oauth.py /path/to/${imap_user}.tokens` in a shell returns an auth token but you are still getting the error in Mutt, then look into `GPG_TTY`. You can isolate for problems here by temporarily removing the passphrase from your GPG key.